# Install libgd 2.1.1 (final) on rhel using cmake?

Tags: linux, cmake, gd

Hoping someone might have seen this or be able to help me reason it through.
I'm installing libgd 2.1.1 for mrtg on Centos/Rhel and see cmake files instead of configure and make files. The wiki and files show no hint of how to install and now I understand the basics of cmake, but still cannot install it correctly.

....yum is not an option to install php-gd

the farthest I've gotten is: cmake CMakeCache.txt  with the results:

```
...The CXX compiler identification is unknown, 
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not
found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- Checking whether system has ANSI C header files
-- ANSI C header files - not found
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Anyone have a thought how to satisify the compiler questions in cmake or a process that might work? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to install a suitable development environment. On CentoS5/RHEL5 you can run
    sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"

and possibly
    sudo yum groupinstall "Development Libraries"